# type definition missing for .svn on jenkins

Tags: typescript, jenkins, svn

I'm building my project on jenkins and since it grabs my project from svn, it creates a .svn folder in the root. When compiling it throws `Cannot find type definition file for '.svn'`.

I've tried to add

```
"exclude": [
        "./.svn",
        ".svn/"
    ]
```

But it does not work.

Any other suggestions? I'm not able to upgrade it's svn client to the newest one.

Comment: On what file is the error reported?

Comment: On none, there is no information on what file that is. I do not use anything related to '.svn' on any of my files. For what i saw, svn creates a .svn folder inside all the folders that it downloads, so that is the problem. I just want to whitelist that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior if I have a `node_modules/@types/.svn` directory.  TypeScript thinks it is a typings package and, by default, tries to load it.  You can stop this by specifying the `types` compiler option.  I filed [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27086) for the automatic type reference directives to ignore hidden directories.

Comment: I'm starting with svn, is there a way to create a file definition inside my application for that specific .svn?

Comment: I don't understand.  `.svn` is not a real package.  Instead of creating a type definition, you should stop the compiler from trying to load `.svn` as a package by specifying the `types` option with the list of all `@types` package names that you _do_ want to load eagerly (excluding `.svn`).